# How to deal with specific route state url parameters on AngularJS or Ionic? How to do route state override on specific parameters？

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, routes, angular-ui-router

My question is simple, but I couldn't find solution anywhere else.

For example I have a normal route state with parameter,

```
  .state('page', {
    url: '/page/:pageid',
    templateUrl: 'templates/pages.html',
    controller: 'pagesCtrl'
  })
```

However for example, if I have 1000 pages, but for the Number 1 and Number 999  pages I have to use another template. How could I simply do this? Something like

```
  .state('page', {
    url: '/page/:pageid',
    templateUrl: 'templates/pages.html',
    controller: 'pagesCtrl'
  })
  .state('page', {
    url: '/page/1',
    templateUrl: 'templates/page1.html',
    controller: 'pagesCtrl'
  })
  .state('page', {
    url: '/page/999',
    templateUrl: 'templates/page999.html',
    controller: 'pagesCtrl'
  })
```

Will this work？I tested, the later 2 options are not overriding the original state with parameter.

If I wish to use the same controller, how to load the 1 and the 999 as the pageid parameter in the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely you shouldn't have two more state for separate template. You should use single generic state which will take `templateUrl` with the help of passed state parameter.

**Code**

```
.state('page', {
    url: '/page/:id',
    templateUrl: function($stateParams){
      var template = $stateParams.id.indexOf([1, 1000]) > -1?'pages.html'
                                                            :'page'+$stateParams.id+'.html';
      return 'templates/'+template ,
    }
    controller: 'pagesCtrl'
})
```

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! So I can put condition check in that function, right?